# Codeigniter form validation set message

Tags: php, codeigniter

A quick one guys, I have the same (ish) form validation rule for the username and email input fields respectively, and i need to set the message of the rules individually. How do i do that?

```
**CODE**

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[2]|is_unique[users.username]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean|is_unique[users.email]');
```

I'm trying to override the message for "is_unique" here,

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique','Username taken');
```

how do i set the message for email as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', '%s is taken.');
```

%s is replaced with the "human name" you applied when setting the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my mistake, I use extended Form_validation of CI and there are 3 fields :)...
As @Rick Calder said the only way to do it is to use, %s which will equal to the inputed name/email..

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', '%s is taken');
```

Comment: That would just prepend "Username taken" to the begining of the default message("field must contain a unique value.")

Comment: first value is the input field name, second the message and 3rd is the condition checked..
If username is not unique you will get the message for it, same for the email.

Comment: Second is name of what is being checked not the message itself. The full message is "The".$second value."field must contain a unique value"